# Google AdWords API access w/ grant_type password

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-ads-api, google-authentication

I have a server side application in python that is calling the AdWords API. Since ClientLogin is being deprecated I'm going to have to use OAuth 2.0.
Basically I need to generate an access token but I don't want any user interaction (to allow access the app) because I'm always using the same username and password on the server, and I'd like to use that username and password to make the AdWords API calls.

I believe the right way to do it is through a grant_type of 'password' oauth2 call to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token.
And this is what I understood from the OAuth2.0 RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-38). The RFC says that the request/query string must contain 3 parameters: grant_type (set to 'password'), username and password.

So I constructed my curl script, which looks like:

```
curl -v --data "grant_type=password&username=user@gmail.com&password=password" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

But I launch the command and I get back with the response from google:

```
{"error" : "invalid_request"}
```

Am I missing something? Is there a simple python library that supports grant_type=password and that has a decent enough documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This grant type isn't supported by the AdWords API, so you can't get an access token using a username and password, but you can get one using a refresh token. Your application just needs to store the refresh token and use it to get new access tokens from the OAuth API. You only need to authorize the account and get the code once; after you input the code into the example, you'll get an access and refresh token.

Here's an outline of the process:

1: Construct an authorization URL:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=1234567890123.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/&access_type=offline`

Note the `access_type` of `offline` that requests a *refresh token*, which you can use to generate new access tokens when they expire.

2: Browse to the URL and authorize your account.

3: Extract the `code` from the redirect page, and request your access and refresh tokens:

`curl -v --data "code=4/v6xr77ewYqhvHSyW6UJ1w7jKwAzu&client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={client_secret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`

This should return your access and refresh tokens:

```
{
  "access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "refresh_token":"1/xEoDL4iW3cxlI7yDbSRFYNG01kVKM2C-259HOF2aQbI"
}
```

4: The access token only lasts for an hour, but **you can use the refresh token to generate a new one without repeating steps 1-3**:

`curl -v --data "client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&refresh_token=1/xEoDL4iW3cxlI7yDbSRFYNG01kVKM2C-259HOF2aQbI&
grant_type=refresh_token" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`

You can find a [Python-specific example here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adspygoogle/adwords/v201309/misc/use_oauth2.py).

Comment: Right, but with the grant type of authorization_code I redirect the user to the auth url where they can accept/allow the application access to their account, and then they would need to copy and paste the code query parameter in the redirect url they received from google (notice code = raw_input('Code: ') in the example). Is there anyway I can do that behind the scenes without any user interaction? In my case there is no user and it's just me, I have a username and password that I can use, the only thing I need to do is get an access token (using my own username and password) and call the API

Comment: I've edited the answer. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: I believe this is what I'm looking for, but instead of writing my own client I'll be using OAuth2Credentials python module which does most of the http calls. I think the trick was that I'm supposed to do this only once to get the credentials, and I can save those credentials permanently then use them to get/refresh access tokens. Thanks, your answer is spot on!